# using add_action without having custom plugin or theme

Tags: plugins, publish, codex

I need to send an email after an author publishes or updates a post.
But I don't like developing custom plugin or theme.
Is there any plugin that runs a php script after publish.
Or where can I insert my code and add have an add_action outside a plugin or theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in "user code" mechanism is WordPress. Your options for running your code are the theme's `functions.php` file, a plugin, or a mu-plugin.

You are aware of the first two options, the first of which you reasonably want to avoid. Writing a simple plugin is [pretty trivial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) so I would not be afraid to try that.

The third option is less well known. If you create a directory called `mu-plugins` in the `wp-content` directory-- in other words, `/wp-content/mu-plugins/`-- and place PHP files in there, WordPress will execute them automatically.

Comment: can I add add_action( 'publish_post', 'notify_new_post' ); to a file in mu-plugins? @s_ha_dum

Comment: Yes. Most hooks should work fine